# Set Bluetooth discoverability in UWP App for HoloLens2

Tags: uwp, bluetooth, hololens, rfcomm

I have written an app that provides a Bluetooth RFCOMM service on HoloLens 2. Without using the settings app, can I make HoloLens2 discoverable for any devices looking for the service? I don't want to force the user to use the settings app just to pair the device. I have been unable to find anything that lets me control the device discoverability using my own app. Is this even possible in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discoverable mode can be started by calling:

```
rfcommServiceProvider.StartAdvertising(streamSocketListener, true);
```

A working example can be found in the RFCOMM samples provided by Microsoft. [Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/b1cb20f191d3fd99ce89df50c5b7d1a6e2382c01/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat/cs/Scenario2_ChatServer.xaml.cs#L109)

Full code:

```
var rfcommServiceProvider = await RfcommServiceProvider.CreateAsync(RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(Constants.RfcommServiceUuid));
//
//Initialize SDP Attributes here
//
var listener = new StreamSocketListener();
var rfcommID = rfcommServiceProvider.ServiceId.AsString();
await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(rfcommID, SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);
try
{
    rfcommServiceProvider.StartAdvertising(listener, true);
    listener.ConnectionReceived += Listener_ConnectionReceived;
    Debug.WriteLine("Now Discoverable");
}
catch
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Failed to set Discoverability.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HoloLens 2 should be discoverable without having to pair it first.  Can you run the client portion of the RFCOMM chat sample ([Bluetooth RFCOMM chat sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/bluetoothrfcommchat/)) and see if your HoloLens 2 device is enumerated?

To make the device discoverable the app needs to call [RfcommServiceProvider.StartAdvertising](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.rfcommserviceprovider.startadvertising?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_Rfcomm_RfcommServiceProvider_StartAdvertising_Windows_Networking_Sockets_StreamSocketListener_System_Boolean_) with radioDicoverable set to true. The RFCOMM chat sample does this in the Foreground server and is discoverable when that is running, but not in the Background server so it is not discoverable when only the background server runs.

Comment: I have just tried the RFCOMM Chat sample. The HoloLens 2 is enumerated only when the HoloLens settings app is open. If the Settings app is not open on the HoloLens, it is not found, even if Bluetooth is turned on using the code provided by Arya Ding.

I am not entirely sure what to include in a sample as this seems to be a fundamental problem. It should be  testable by: 
- Turn HoloLens bluetooth on. 
- Close HoloLens Settings app. 
- Make sure device not yet paired. 
- Try to find HoloLens using another device.

Comment: Hi Chris, I initially experienced the same behavior you described so I had a discussion with the Bluetooth developers.  They said that calling RfcommServiceProvider.StartAdvertising with radioDicoverable set to true is all that is needed to make the device discoverable.  That is exactly what the Devices page in Settings does.  I looked at the RfComm chat sample again and noticed that only the foreground chat server calls StartAdvertising.  Apparently I was only testing with Background Chat server because the Foreground Chat server does work.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thank you for looking deeper into this issue. Is there a way to do this with the Background Server too?

Comment: Hi Chris, In order to make the device discoverable you'll still have to call RfcommServiceProvider.StartAdvertising.